# How to atomically update multiple kv entries with consul?

Tags: consul

Let's assume we have the following key value pairs imported to consul:

```
curl -X PUT -d 'val1' http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/stuff/key1
curl -X PUT -d 'val2' http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/stuff/key2
curl -X PUT -d 'val3' http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/stuff/key3
```

I it possible to atomically update them all together?

The reason I am asking is that we use consule for configuration management and do not won't that depending key value pairs are only partially updated and thus in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible right now. There's an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/886) that tracks this.

Comment: This feature was recently merged into Master.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script for it.
Sample shell script goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is used to bootstrap the following properties into the
# Consul KV store under the config/size key context.

setproperty()
{
    # Defines the property in the Consul KV if the key is undefined.
    #
    # Arguments:
    # 1 - Consul KV property value
    # 2 - Consul KV property URL
    # 3 - Optional boolean that specifies whether the an updated value
    #     should be echoed (defaults to true).
    # Returns
    # N/A

    local key_value=$1
    local key_url=$2
    local echo_is_enabled=true

    if [ $# == 3 ]
    then
       local echo_is_enabled=$3
    fi

    # Note:
    # The ?case=0 flag means to turn the PUT into a Check-And-Set operation,
    # so that the value will only be put if the key does not already exist.

    local was_updated=$(curl -s -X PUT -d "$key_value" $key_url?cas=0)

    if [ true == $echo_is_enabled ] && [ true == $was_updated ]
    then
         echo "ConsulKV[URL=$key_url][value=$key_value]"
    fi

}
readonly -f setproperty

setproperties()
{  
    local val1="val1"
    local url_val1="http://localhost:8500/v1/kv/stuff/key1"
    if [ -z "$kv_val1" ] && [ -n "$val1" ]
    then
        setproperty "$val1" "$url_val1"
    fi
}

main() 
{
    local url="http://localhost:8500"

    # HTTP response code
    local http_response_code=0

    # timeout in units of seconds to wait for Consul KV to respond
    timeout_sec=120

    # while loop sleep time in units of seconds
    local sleep_time_sec=5

    # URL of the consul health service endpoint
    url_health_service_consul="$url/v1/health/service/consul"

    # wait until Consul is available or max wait exceeded
    while [ 200 -ne $http_response_code ] && [ $SECONDS -lt $timeout_sec ]
    do
        http_response_code=$(curl -w %{response_code} -s --output /dev/null       $url_health_service_consul)
        if [ 200 -eq $http_response_code ]
        then
            break
        fi
        sleep $sleep_time_sec
    done

    if [ 200 -eq $http_response_code ]
    then
        # set properties if not already defined in Consul KV
        setproperties
    else
        echo "Unable to access: $url_health_service_consul"
    fi

}

readonly -f main

main
```

Add all the key value pairs you want to add in the setproperties method

Comment: If the keys are already present in the consul, the values will be overridden by the values in the script